# Create time series of daily avg relative humidity using GFS

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

How to create time series of daily avg relative humidity using GFS: Global Forecast System 384-Hour Predicted Atmosphere Data for the year 2021 using the following code?

```
var region = ee.Geometry(Map.getBounds(true))
// Strip time off current date/time
var today = ee.Date(new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0])

var collection = ee.ImageCollection('NOAA/GFS0P25')
  .select('total_precipitation_surface')
  // Might not have any data for today, so include yesterday too
  .filterDate(today.advance(-1, 'day'), today.advance(1, 'day'))
  // Sort so latest can be picked by taking first
  .sort('system:time_start', false)

var forecasts = ee.ImageCollection(
  [23, 24, 48, 72, 96].map(forecast) // Pick forecasts for these hours
)

Map.addLayer(forecasts, {min: 0, max: 0.001}, 'forecasts', false)

var chart = ui.Chart.image.series({
  imageCollection: forecasts, 
  region: region,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), 
  scale: forecasts.first().projection().nominalScale(),
  xProperty: 'date'
}).setChartType('ColumnChart');

print(chart)

function forecast(hours) {
  var image = collection
    .filterMetadata('forecast_hours', 'equals', hours)
    // Since colleciton is sorted descending, if there are more than 
    // one forecast, first() will give the latest.
    .first()
  var date = image.date().advance(hours, 'hours')
  return image
    .set('date', date.format())
}
```